# filling the area under a plotted function in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, fill, pattern

For the shown MWE:

- I need to fill the area under the function plotted in tikz using the "Plot Command". However, using the "Fill" option in the "Draw command" does not yeild any results.
- I need to fill the area under the plot in one occasion and in another I need to fill the area above the plot.
- Also can I replace the fill with a pattern such as vertical lines....
- In adition, is there a way to fill/hatch only a certain region within such plot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5](0,0) grid(15,24);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,6)}]
\draw[thick,color=red,fill=yellow,domain=0:6] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,fill=yellow,domain=6:12] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output for plotted function using Tikz]

Comment: If you want to draw graphs, look up data visualization (TikZ) or use pgfplots (and fill between).  Otherwise, provide a complete path for \fill, including all sides.

Comment: @  John Kormylo, whey use "Data visualization" while plotting  a function using a math engine is most accurate?

Comment: Datat visualization has more to do with axes, grids and converting "furlongs per fortnight" into cm.  Also, pgfmath is not accurate by any stretch of the immagination.

Comment: However, mkaing a path or bezier curve for parabolic curves (3rd, 4th degree equations and above) is troblesome, that is why using plot equations is easier in such casese. I only used this function as a simple example however, there are occasions where I need to plot 4th degree equations, making a path or bezier curve for such equation, or even using the Hobby package is very troublesome in such case.

Comment: What does "the area under the plot" mean? -Vertically down to the bounding box? What do you mean by "a certain region"?

Comment: Area under the plot: area inside the red triangle (assuming an upper line = axis, connects its ends), a certain region, if I want to fill the area alone only a certain length and a certain height

Comment: If I understand what you mean:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5](0,0) grid(15,10);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,6)}]
\fill [yellow] (0,-1.5) -- plot[domain=0:6]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=0:6] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});

\fill [yellow] (6,0)-- plot[domain=6:12]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=6:12] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: It will be much easier if the compilation output and the code are uploaded in the form of an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5](0,0) grid(15,10);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,6)}]
\fill [yellow] (0,-1.5) -- plot[domain=0:6]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=0:6] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});

\fill [yellow] (6,0)-- plot[domain=6:12]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=6:12] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

code2:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5](0,0) grid(15,10);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,6)}]
\fill [yellow]  plot[domain=0:6]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)})--(6,0);
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=0:6] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});

\fill [yellow] (6,0)-- plot[domain=6:12]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=6:12] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output:

[image]

code3:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=0.5](0,0) grid(15,10);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,6)}]
\fill [yellow] (0,-1.5) -- plot[domain=0:6]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=0:6] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*(\x*6)/(12)});

\fill [yellow]  plot[domain=6:12]  (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)})--(12,-1.5);
\draw[thick,color=red,domain=6:12] plot (\x, {0.1*(5*-1)*((12-\x)*(6))/(12)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the point, however, is there any manual or reference to emphasize the logic of the used coding?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572376/creating-a-fill-pattern-for-a-parabolic-plot